# Why do tetrahedral organic molecules show stereo-isomerism, but not tetrahedral transition metal complexes?

Tags: stereochemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, isomers

[image: Example of octahedral cis-trans]Both types of molecules show different arrangements of the molecule in space, so they should qualify for optical isomerism right?

Comment: Could you give an example of a tetrahedral transition metal complex with four different ligands that might have an optical isomer?

Comment: Actually they can and you didn't mix up anything. It may be hard to come up with an example that wouldn't involve organic ligands, but it's definitely possible that metal would be center of chirality.

Comment: Mithoron is right for tetrahedral metal complexes but the compounds you have shown are octahedral. But some octahedral metal complexes *can* also be chiral (the cis compound you drew has, if it is stable and the bi.dentate ligands don't swap around quickly, two mirror images)